# .innerHTML doesn't work inside function

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

```
document.getElementById("boxoffice[0][total]").innerHTML = "Working";
function totaltest() {
 document.getElementById("boxoffice[0][total]").innerHTML = "Not Working";
}
```

For some reason, the above innerHTML works perfectly OUTSIDE a function, but not inside...any ideas as to the cause??

Comment: What is boxoffice?

Comment: are you calling `totaltest()`?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide more details. What calls the function? Is it called *after* the element with that id exists? Do you get any errors in the console?

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure that you're calling `totaltest()`, because the code that you've posted is completely valid.

See the following code, it works fine:

```js
document.getElementById("aa").innerHTML = "test 1";

function totaltest() {
    document.getElementById("bb").innerHTML = "test 2";
}

totaltest();
```

```html
<p id="aa"></p><br>
<p id="bb"></p>
```

Comment: +1. Side note - If you're calling it, please include this in the original question. Would be useful for returning visitors.

Answer (score 1):

You should do

```
document.getElementById("boxoffice[0][total]").innerHTML = "Working";
function totaltest() {
 document.getElementById("boxoffice[0][total]").innerHTML = "Not Working";
}
totaltest()
```

its not working because you are not invoking totaltest